# using ID from a selected item in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selection

I want to use the ID of selected item  from the list below to use it in other function, how can I do it please , am using JSF;

I have tried  many times but in vain !!  please help

[image: this picture may help you to understand my goal]

here is my code in jsf:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:60%  ; padding-left:25%"
    layout="grid">
    <p:dataTable var="convert"
        value="#{convertirDeviseCtr.listeDevise}" style="width:70%"
        id="convertir">
        <f:facet name="header">Liste des devises</f:facet>


        <p:column selectionMode="single">
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/flags/#{convert.libSiglDev}.png"
                id="img" style="width:20px ; height:20px" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="#{convert.libDevDev}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:panel style="padding-top:40%">
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="Saisir montant :" />
        <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
        <p:keyboard id="image" value="#{keyboardView.value8}"
            showMode="button" buttonImageOnly="true"
            buttonImage="/images/icons/keyboardpencil.png" keypadOnly="true"
            style="width:150px ; height:20px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <p:selectOneButton value="" style="margin-left:35%">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Achat" itemValue="A" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Vente" itemValue="V" />
        </p:selectOneButton>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p:commandButton value="Convertir" icon="ui-icon-refresh"
            style="margin-left:40%"></p:commandButton>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p:outputLabel>Resultat :</p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value=""></p:inputText>
    </p:panel>
</p:panelGrid>
```

thanks in advance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `selection` attribute of `<p:dataTable>`. The value of the `selection` attribute must be a property of a backing bean where the selected value will be stored. For example:

```
...
<p:dataTable var="convert"
    value="#{convertirDeviseCtr.listeDevise}" style="width:70%"
    id="convertir" selection="#{someController.selectionProperty}">
...
```

More information about `<p:dataTable>` tag and the different types of selection modes:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: thanks :) 
I used the same example  before but I made some errors so that's why I failed ; Now I'm more concentrated;

thanks again Sir , it works :)

Comment: As can, as you refer to, all be seen in the PrimeFaces showcase. Wonder why questions like this get asked...